# mysql autoincrement whats the correct type?

Tags: mysql

I want to make an autoincrement primary index column when making a table.

It must be an int (ie. able to get into the millions)

On the mysql manual page, it shows 2 different types of int, one that goes from -ve to +ve and one that goes from 0 to +ve.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

I want my autoincrement to start at 1 not -ve millions.  For my new column then, which should I use?  How do I make it choose the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an ID, the unsigned type (0 ... MAX) is the one that makes sense. You are unlikely to want negative IDs.

Comment: Agreed, negative ids do not make sense in most cases for PKs.